# Объединить несколько таблиц в одном запросе

Tags: php

Такая задача. Есть 4 таблицы: **i_list**, **m_list**, **a_list**, **y_list**. Количество полей в них разное. Мне нужно как то объединить их в одну, временную таблицу, чтобы я мог перебрать получившийся массив через while.

Т.е.

```
while ($re = $query->fetch_array()) echo $re['name'] ...
```

В каждой таблице есть поле **sid**, которое служит условием. Я плохо понимаю в JOIN'ах, поэтому прошу помощи, кому не сложно.

Я пробовал так:

```
$query = $bds->query("
SELECT
ml.*, 
il.*,
al.*

FROM 
m_list ml
OUTER JOIN i_list il ON ml.sid = il.sid
OUTER JOIN a_list al ON ml.sid = al.sid   
");
```

Получилось - ничего путного.
Хочу, чтобы запрос был аналогичен такой конструкции:

```
$query = $bds->query("SELECT * FROM <table-name> WHERE sid='$var'");
```

Но как сделать - не представляю.

upd

```
$query = $bds->query("
SELECT
ml.header, 
il.header

FROM 
m_list ml WHERE ml.sid='$var'
LEFT JOIN i_list il ON il.sid = '$var'

");
$r = print_r($query->fetch_array(),1);
echo '<pre>'.$r.'</pre>';
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117907/discussion-on-question-by-podpisochka1288------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $bds->query("SELECT 
   ml.header 
   FROM `ml` 
   WHERE ml.SID='$var' 
  UNION 
   SELECT il.header 
   FROM `il` 
   WHERE il.SID='$var'");
```

**Результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**таблицы**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это почти то, что нужно. А как быть, например, если кол-во столбцов в таблицах различается ? UNION же требует, чтобы кол-во столбцов было одинаково..поэтому писал, что кол-во столбцов разное :)
Пример - `https://ibb.co/5nPMMGW`

Comment: тогда нужно вместо таблицы во FROM части подставить запрос урезающий поля

Comment: Эх, ладно. И на этом спасибо, попробую загуглить )

Загуглил. Достаточно дописать null )

Comment: SELECT A.SID FROM ( SELECT ml.SID FROM ml ) AS A  - вот пример, т.е. тут я выбираю не из ml а из выборки где только ml.SID, таким образом можно урезать поля из которых потом будет выбирать SELECT

Comment: http://old.code.mu/sql/ вот еще хороший ресурс попался по SQL

Comment: запросы бывают очень большими или сложными в таких случаях лучше составить те которые внутри отдельно а потом уже объеденить в один большой